# How can I ingest random-formatted dates in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, formatting

I have a login tracker log file that is an amalgamation of multiple sources. The sources (and there are many) use a variety of date formats. I am using the resultant $objList object to hand these over to a SQL Database. When I try to then use SQL Queries, I am missing data.

Here is a small slice of the raw input, from September 2007:

1. Logon;Username;Server01;10/09/2007 09:56:40
2. Logon;Username;Server02;10/09/2007 11:26:20
3. Logon;Username;Server03;9/11/2007 10:16:27 AM
4. Logon;Username;Server04;11/09/2007 12:28:45

Notice the 3rd one is American format, the others are European. I need a way of getting these things to ingest into a script in a consistent date format. There are literally hundreds of thousands of lines in this file, so it is not realistic to go through by hand and modify anything.

Here is what I have so far.

```
  IF ($SplitUsr.Count -eq '4')
    {
        $varAction = $SplitUsr[0]
        IF ($varAction -eq 'Logon')
        {
            $varActionx = $SplitUsr[0].Trim()
            $varUser = $SplitUsr[1].Trim()
            $varHostname = $SplitUsr[2].Trim()
            $varTime = $SplitUsr[3].Trim()

            try {$datetime = [dateTime]::Parse("$varTime",([Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB')))}
            catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException]
            {
                $datetime = [dateTime]::Parse("$varTime",([Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-US')))
            }

                $objLogon = New-Object PSObject
                $objLogon | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "Entry" -Value $intCount
                $objLogon | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "Logon" -Value '1'
                $objLogon | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "User" -Value $varUser
                $objLogon | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value $varHostname
                $objLogon | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value $datetime
                $objList += $objLogon
```

Unfortunately, this is parsing them into

1. 10 September 2007 09:56:40
2. 10 September 2007 11:26:20
3. 09 November 2007 10:16:27
4. 11 September 2007 12:28:45

You can see that the 3rd example, the one with the American formatting in the raw data, came out as November instead of the 11 September (inverting the 9 and 11).

The same thing is happening all over the place. When I look at the SQL entries for December, here's what I'm getting:

1. 07 December 2007 09:53:33
2. 07 December 2007 11:37:48
3. 12 July 2007 13:25:02
4. 07 December 2007 13:26:38
5. 07 December 2007 15:04:56

You can see that the third one somehow got the 12 and 7 inverted. This is the problem I'm trying to resolve.

Any suggestions?

Edit: A few more samples:

1. Logon;Username;Server01;18/11/2008 11:19:08
2. Logon;Username;Server02;18/11/2008 11:21:46 AM
3. Logon;Username;Server03;18/11/2008 14:28:30
4. Logon;Username;Server04;19/11/2008 09:55:50
5. Logon;Username;Servername;19/11/2008 14:14:09
6. Logon;Username;Servername;19/11/2008 14:19:56
7. Logon;Username;Servername;20/11/2008 12:19:57 PM

Not all the AM/PM indicate American formatting, unfortunately.

Comment: You might have better luck with the `[datetime]::tryparse` method.  Also, your example doesn't track.  You say "You can see" at the end with regards to getting the 12 & 7 inverted, but I can't see because you didn't post any raw data corresponding to that error for me to trace it back.  Your small slice of raw data comes from September, but your "obvious" example from either July or December.  Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on creating a good example and see if you can't edit your post a bit.

Comment: The first example I posted is also incorrect. There's a November in the middle of the September outputs, which is 9 and 11 inverted. I only added the examples of July and December, because they pop a bit more, visually, since the words themselves are different lengths. I'll re-word to make that more clear.

Comment: In order to make this work, you have to look at your data and come up with a set of rules which **always** work.  If it looks like **this** then interpret it this way.  If it looks like **this other thing** then interpret it this other way.  Since you have access to the full list, you are more likely to be able to figure out a set of rules which work.  Once you do, write a converter for each type of data and you've got your answer.  I hope you are able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "KI" you was speaking of:

```
$dates = @( '10/09/2007 09:56:40',
            '09/10/2007 11:26:20',
            '10/09/2007 10:16:27 AM',
            '10/09/2007 12:28:45' )

    $cultureUS = [CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
    $cultureEU = [CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")

    $maxDays   = 2  # Max. allowed difference between current date and former date in days

    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $dates.Count; $i++ ) {

        $currentDate = [DateTime]::Parse( $dates[ $i ],$cultureEU )

        if( $i -gt 0 ) {
            $diffPast = New-TimeSpan -Start $lastDate -End $currentDate
        }
        else {
            $diffPast = New-TimeSpan -Start $currentDate -End $currentDate
        }

        if( $diffPast.Days -gt $maxDays ) {

            # check if month of current date is day of last date => culture issue
            if( $currentDate.Day -eq $lastDate.Month -or $currentDate.Month -eq $lastDate.Day ) {
                $currentDate = [DateTime]::Parse( $dates[ $i ],$cultureUS )
            }
        }

        $currentDate

        $lastDate = $currentDate

    }
```

Comment: I gave that a shot. Unfortunately, not all the AM/PM indicate American date formats. I found a few from trying this. I added them to the original post.

Comment: @RickRDR If not all AM/PM are US format, how should a program know, if 1/2/2020 is 1st February or 2nd January?

Comment: @f6a4 that's kind of what I was hoping to get answered here. All I know is that there's a big bunch of lines that, to a human, are clearly (for example) December, regardless of which way the dates are written. I was hoping to get some logic that might be able to help me programmatically do the same via PoSh.

Comment: Try again. This script checks if former date is near current date. If not, check if it is a date culture problem. Assumption: The first date is EU-culture!!!

Comment: This is getting me closer to a logic I can use. Since these are all logons for a particular user, I will have to account for things like annual leave, or bank holiday weekends, or whatever, but this definitely gets me a step in the right direction. I'm going to use this as my foundation and build from here. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, not all the AM/PM indicate American date formats.

**Without additional information, you cannot solve your problem**, because of inherent ambiguities:

```
9/11/2007 10:16:27 AM
```

It is impossible to tell whether this is an `en-US` (US) timestamp that refers to the 11th day of September (month first), or a `en-GB` (UK)  timestamp that refers to  9th day of November (day first).

Only if either the first or the second component *happens to be* `13` or higher is `en-US` or `en-GB` *implied*, and only such timestamps would be handled correctly by the `try` / `catch` logic in your question.

---

**If you provide an additional constraint that all dates must meet, a solution is possible.**

For instance, if you know that all dates fall into a *given month*:

```
# The month that all log entries are expected to fall into:
$refMonth = 9  # September, for example.

# Create an array of the cultures to use for parsing:
[cultureinfo[]] $cultures = 'en-GB', 'en-US'

'11/9/2007 17:02:15',
'9/11/2007 05:02:44 PM',
'11/9/2007 05:03:01 PM' | ForEach-Object {

   $ok = $false; [datetime] $dt = 0
   foreach ($culture in $cultures) {
     $ok = [datetime]::TryParse($_, $culture, 'None', [ref] $dt) -and $dt.Month -eq $refMonth
     if ($ok) { break }
   }
   if (-not $ok) { Write-Error "Not recognized as a date in the expected month: $_" }
   else { $date } # Output the resulting date.

}
```

The above yields the following, showing that all dates were parsed as month `9` (September) dates:

```
Tuesday, September 11, 2007 5:02:15 PM
Tuesday, September 11, 2007 5:02:44 PM
Tuesday, September 11, 2007 5:03:01 PM
```

Comment: I was afraid of this. The way we've been able to "tell" so far, has been to look at the lines above and below. If I, as a human, look at the lines above or below, I am able to tell if one is wrong. In other words, as I scan down the list and I see a bunch of 6 December followed by something 12 July again followed by a bunch of December, then I know that this one is wrong. But I don't know how to give that kind of AI functionality to PowerShell.